# Get top left of pixel in image having alpha set 1 using imagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I need to find the x coordinate of first pixel along with y coordinate having alpha set 1. I have a transparent image on which i have a black border rectangle. Now i need to find the rectangle's top and left.

For example, check image:
[image: tranparent outer rectangle]

So i thought of, if somehow i can get first non transparent point in image i can get its coordinates and know about it.

Can it be done using Imagick in php. I read about pixelIterator, but how do i use it to do this? any suggestions or thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You could loopt trough all the pixels and use the [Imagick::getImagePixelColor(x,y)](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimagepixelcolor.php) function to read the color.

Comment: Thanks.. but we dont have any thing which will just take out the pixel with the color?, or i have to manually loop over only is the option.

Comment: Maybe there is some library which can do that for you. But i think it's easier to write that loop by yourself than to find that library.

Answer (score 1):

Three years later, and just for kicks, here are some thoughts on a way of approaching this with ImageMagick from the command line...

First, you can extract the transparency channel, using `-alpha extract <filename>`, but I don't really want the file so I can pipe it out to another `convert` command to threshold out anything where the alpha is not 1 (I assume a 16-bit quantisation, i.e. 65535=1) and then ask ImageMagick how it would trim that image to the smallest bounding box by using `-format %@ -write info:`

```
convert rectangle.png -alpha extract png:- | convert - -threshold 65534 -format %@ -write info: alpha.png
```

**Output**

```
91x118+80+81
```

That tells me the that the bounding box for the thresholded transparency is 91px wide by 118 pixels tall and it starts 80px across from the top left corner and most importantly that it starts 81 pixels down from the top - I now know the y coordinate is 81.

Whilst we don't actually need it to find the pixel you seek, it helps show what I am doing, so let me just draw that box so you can see it:

```
convert rectangle.png -stroke red -fill none -draw "rectangle 80,81 170,198" fyi.png
```

[image]

Now I can crop just the 81st line out of the image and look for the first white pixel with `grep` and exit as soon as I have found it.

```
convert alpha.png -crop x1+0+81 txt: | grep -m1 "#FFFFFF"
```

**Output**

```
147,0: (65535,65535,65535)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
```

So, that tells me that the first white pixel is 147 across, so I know the x coordinate too. Therefore the pixel you seek is at 147,81.